# Bootstrap Auto-complete Error: Cannot read property " " of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, bootstrap-4

I m trying to use Bootstrap autocomplete, with Django ..
I Tested the calls and the ajax request sent successfully to my views, 
but i did not get response in my form.. 
due to an error appeared in the console of type:
*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'updatedItem' of undefined*

The Error Appears multiple times with different names alternative to 'updatedItem' ---- and appears when i start typing in the form..

... What I M Missing Here Please!

**views.py**

```
def SearchMedical(request):
    results_pharmacy = None
    if request.GET.get('q'):
        q = request.GET['q']
        results_pharmacy = PharmacyDetails.objects.filter(name__istartswith = q).values_list('name',flat=True)
        json = list(results_pharmacy)
        return JsonResponse(json, safe=False)
```

**search.html**

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/xcash/bootstrap-autocomplete@master/dist/latest/bootstrap-autocomplete.min.js"></script>


       <form method="GET" action="{% url 'searchMedical' %}" id="searchMedical">

<input class="basicAutoComplete form-control rounded-0" autocomplete="off"  type="text" placeholder="Pharmacy name">
</form>


<script>
$('.basicAutoComplete').autoComplete({
    resolverSettings: {
        url: '{% url "searchMedical" %}'
    },
    minLength: 1

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Found my Error!
I forgot to encapsulate my JQuery code inside the document ready event: $( document ).ready()

I COPED THIS EXPLANATION FROM SOME DOCS:
*Whenever you use jQuery to manipulate your web page, you wait until the document ready event has fired. The document ready event signals that the DOM of the page is now ready, so you can manipulate it without worrying that parts of the DOM has not yet been created. The document ready event fires before all images etc. are loaded, but after the whole DOM itself is ready.*

*A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.*

Now My Code Works Fine after the following edit:
(and you can use it in django)
search.html

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
$('.basicAutoComplete').autoComplete({
    resolverSettings: {
        url: '{% url "ajax_search" %}'
    },
    minLength: 1
});
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very-very much.
I spent a whole day to find out why my auto-complete doesn't work and was completely desperate, when I found your answer... and a solution to my problem. :-)

Comment: @PaulZakharov That's really makes me happy, and that's why we are here for each others :-)

Comment: God bless you good Man